# how to get index of particular value in array list in android

Tags: android

I implement a bean class and then I create arraylist like below example.But I couldn't get index in particular name.I want to know how to search where employee name = “xxx” in array List in android.

eg:- let say I have a bean employee {name, number}

and have a arra list ->
**"array_list type is employee "**

need to search where employee name = “xxx” in array list
      How I implement it?
           thanks!!!

Comment: Hi Kushan.. why something in list in android? I mean native android user Java for programming,so question should be how something in list in java? Hope you get answered. Its simply indexOf()method of list.

Comment: Actually I want to without any loop.such that dirrectly access arrylist usnig key value.then whethe if it have a match values

Comment: You might want to look at my answer. I think it's what you may be looking for

Comment: My hope Answer is like this.....  String myArray={"12","23","10","22","10"};
      Boolean=Arrays.asList(myArray).contains("23");            But this is for array.I want arraylist

Comment: You want something to do with employee names as well right?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the method `IndexOf()` of `java.util.ArrayList`

An implementation is like

```
ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>(5);
// use add() method to add values in the list
arrlist.add("G");
arrlist.add("E");
arrlist.add("F");
arrlist.add("M");


  // retrieving the index of element "E"

int retval=arrlist.IndexOf("E");
```

So, `retval` is the index of your desired object

Comment: Honestly, looking at what he wants, I think he was looking for `Map` but didn't know it existed

Answer (score 1):

You can start a for loop on the arrayList. 
For each index get the employee object from list and from that object get the employee name. Compare this name with xxx and if it matches, store that value of i in some variable and break the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Zahan's answer is right. However, the complexity of looking up an element in an `ArrayList` is *O(n)*.

However, seeing the description, I think what you are looking for is a `Map`.

What a `Map` does, is stores information corresponding to a particular key. For example, I can have the Employee ID numbers as the **key** and the corresponding name of that employee as the **value**. You can read more about the tutorial I have written [here](http://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-hash-maps-and-hash-tables-efficiently-in-competitive-programming/answer/Shreyans-Sheth-1?share=1) or the generic one [here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/).

I must mention that `Map` in JAVA is an *Interface*, so to implement it, you can use the `HashMap` *class* (uses hashing) which offers Amortized *O(1)* lookup time which is what you want to be shooting for.

Here is the implementation for storing the Employee id numbers as the *key* and the employoee names as the *value*. I must also mention that *keys* in a `Map` must always be unique. You will learn all this in the tutorial. I will assume that you have the Employee names and id numbers stored in an array of objects of class 'employee'. Here goes:

```
    employee[] data=new employee[100];
    /*code in this to store in this whatever data you have to
     */
    Map<Integer, String> lookupEmpName=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        lookupEmpName.put(data[i].getEmpNumber,data[i].getName); //Store the key as the number and the name as the value
    String name=lookupEmpName.get(1234); //name will store the corresponding name of the employee if it exists or stores null
```

I hope this is what you were looking for. I'd be gald to help you out